# Java Regex to match space or beginning of string

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to match all instances of a word that don't have a prefix or suffix attached, basically any instance of the word that is preceded by a space or appears at the beginning of the string and is followed by either a space or punctuation. The following should match:

```
"This is the word."
"word is this."
```

And the following should not:

```
"This is preword."
"wordness is this."
```

My original solution was this:

```
(^|\\s)word(\\s|,|\\.)
```

But it does not capture the case in which the word appears at the beginning of the string. 
How can I correctly use the carat to do this?

Comment: Can you provide some expected input and output?

Comment: if the input contains only the string `word` then you need to specify the end pattern `$`

Comment: Why not just use word boundaries `\\b(word)\\b`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems that you are looking for [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) `\b`.

Possible problem you are facing is that regex like `\sword\s` will consume spaces surrounding searched words, so these spaces will not be reused to find next word after currently matched.

Example

```
foo foo foo foo foo
```

If you would like to look for `foo` which could for example have

- before it start of the string or some whitespace
- after it end of the string or whitespace

so regex could look like `(^|\\s)foo(\\s|$)`

you would match

```
foo foo foo foo foo
^^^^   ^^^^^   ^^^^
```

second `foo` wouldn't be matched because space before it was already used by match of first `foo`,

```
foo foo foo foo foo
   X^^^^             cant use space marked with `X`
```

so next substring would be

```
foo foo foo foo foo
       ^^^^^
```

and then

```
foo foo foo foo foo
               ^^^^
```

To solve this problem you can use `\b` which represents place between characters from `\w` (`a-z` `A-Z` `0-9` and `_`) and any character which is not in `\w`.

So try with  `\bword\b` instead (which in Java String needs to be written as `"\\bword\\b"`)

---

BTW you probably should surround your word with [quotation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html#qe) `\Q...\E` if it contains regex [special characters](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html#special).

So your regex can look like `"\\b\\Qword\\E\\b"`.

Answer (score 4):

Java regex supports the word boundary `\b` metacharacter:

```
\bword\b
```

Note that [Java will accept any valid Unicode character for the word.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)